# Configuring C2950 with 802.1X/PEAP and RADIUS server

Tags: cisco, radius, peap

I am setting up 802.1X security on a LAN which has a C2950 switch that controls access from the WLAN to the Ethernet LAN. I plan to use PEAP. I read this the [Cisco article on configuring 802.1X security](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2950/software/release/12.1_9_ea1/configuration/guide/Sw8021x.html)

> the Remote Authentication Dial-In User Service (RADIUS) security system with Extensible Authentication Protocol (EAP) extensions is the only supported authentication server; it is available in Cisco Secure Access Control Server version 3.0.

A RADIUS server is required, however, I have Ubuntu Server available, not Cisco ACS, and don't know how to set up a RADIUS server for this scenario.

Is there a way to set up 802.1X/PEAP that it will work with the C2950? And how would you set up the RADIUS server on Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 1):

The Free Radius server is an open source Radius server available for all major Linux distributions, including Ubuntu: http://freeradius.org/doc/ You will need to configure the wireless access point to send authentication requests to the Radius server.

From the Cisco Document:

> Configuring the Switch-to-RADIUS-Server Communication
>
> RADIUS security servers are identified by their host name or IP
>   address, host name and specific UDP port numbers, or IP address and
>   specific UDP port numbers. The combination of the IP address and UDP
>   port number creates a unique identifier, which enables RADIUS requests
>   to be sent to multiple UDP ports on a server at the same IP address.
>   If two different host entries on the same RADIUS server are configured
>   for the same service—for example, authentication—the second host entry
>   configured acts as the fail-over backup to the first one. The RADIUS
>   host entries are tried in the order that they were configured.
>
> Beginning in privileged EXEC mode, follow these steps to configure the
>   RADIUS server parameters on the switch. This procedure is required.
>
> ```
>    Command     Purpose
> ```
>
> Step 1
>
> configure terminal
>
> Enter global configuration mode.
>
> Step 2
>
> **radius-server host {hostname | ip-address} auth-port port-number key string      Configure the RADIUS server parameters on the switch. For
>   hostname | ip-address, specify the host name or IP address of the
>   remote RADIUS server.**
>
> For auth-port port-number, specify the UDP destination port for
>   authentication requests. The default is 1812.
>
> For key string, specify the authentication and encryption key used
>   between the switch and the RADIUS daemon running on the RADIUS server.
>   The key is a text string that must match the encryption key used on
>   the RADIUS server.
>
> Note Always configure the key as the last item in the radius-server
>   host command syntax because leading spaces are ignored, but spaces
>   within and at the end of the key are used. If you use spaces in the
>   key, do not enclose the key in quotation marks unless the quotation
>   marks are part of the key. This key must match the encryption used on
>   the RADIUS daemon.
>
> If you want to use multiple RADIUS servers, re-enter this command.